# IIS express 8 webpage is not available

Tags: iis-express

I set up a site using IIS Manager but cannot get it to serve a static web page from my local file system (get the above error) the only way I can serve it is to copy the page assets into the directory for the default site (C:\inetpub\wwwroot).  I can't find any documentation that I can understand for IIS.  How can I set the root of localhost for IIS to my project folder?

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/hh831515.aspx

Comment: I think by BY Pointing the Default website to the file system, we can do this. 
IIS -> Default Website -> Manage Webstie -> Advance Setting -> physical path

Comment: Nope, I tried that... the only physical path that works is the wwwroot one.

Comment: @Dreamweaver, I followed the steps in the link you provided 100 times already and it never works, the page never loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short, easy answer is "you can't". The better way is to move your project to the wwwroot folder.

You can, however, link additional folders in IIS Manager.  If you link your project folder under wwwroot, you could access it at localhost\MyProjectFolder

Comment: OK, thanks so much: I was going insane with this. When you say "link" do you mean a virtual directory?

Comment: OK, I can do that...  Is that what visual studio does under the hood?  I'm trying to set up a localhost for webstorm and I want to use virtual directories for shared assets for example.  Is this the way to go?

Comment: if you can't do it why do they offer the option? It seems ridiculous no?

Comment: The way I use it, I just leave the server admin stuff under wwwroot and then use folders and virtual directories to house all my content.

Comment: In "full blown" IIS, you can create additional web roots where ever you please that have nothing to do with inetpub/wwwroot.  I'm not sure if the same is true of IIS Express.